# Evaluate the integral $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)\, ds$ where $f$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Evaluate
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)\, ds \, .
$$
My attempt: I was using the Leibniz rule

```
          lim 1/h{(d(t+h)/ds  f(t+h)  -d(t-h)/ds  f(t-h)}
           h→0

     and i got lim 1/h{dt/ds (f+h)-f(t-h)   + dh/ds{(f(t+h) - f(t-h)}
                h→0
```

Now I don"t know the further step....
I would be more thankful for  rectifying my mistake..

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is just one part of the FTC; it's in a zillion texts.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$

$f$ is continuous at $t$ thus exists $h>0$ such that $|f(s)-f(t)|< \epsilon ,\forall s \in (t-h,t+h)$

Now

$$|\frac{1}{h} \int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)ds-2f(t)|=2|\frac{1}{2h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)ds-\frac{1}{2h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(t)ds|$$ $$\leq2 \frac{1}{2h} \int_{t-h}^{t+h}|f(s)-f(t)| \leq 2\epsilon \frac{1}{2h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}ds=2\epsilon$$

Therefore $\frac{1}{h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)ds \rightarrow 2f(t)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 0):

We consider a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Let $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $h>0$. In particular, $f$ is continuous on $[t-h,t+h]$. According to the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus),
$$
\int_{t-h}^{t+h} f(s)\, ds = F(t+h)-F(t-h)
$$
where $F$ denotes a primitive of $F$ over $[t-h,t+h]$. Now, the [definition of the derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition) gives
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h} f(s)\, ds &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h} + \frac{F(t-h)-F(t)}{-h} \\ &= 2 F'(t) \\ &= 2 f(t) \, .
\end{aligned}

Comment: thank u @ harry49  but answer  is 2f(t)

Comment: thank u @ harry49  but im not getting why u take both numerator and denominator 2

Comment: thanks a lot.. now im getting  and understand ur answer @ Harry 49

Answer (score 0):

Using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) and continuity of $f$ 
\begin{gather*}\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int\limits_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)~ds = \left[\frac{0}{0}\right] \overset{LH}= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\frac{d}{dh}\left(\int\limits_{t-h}^{t+h}f(s)~ds\right)}{\frac{d}{dh}\left({h} \right)} = \\
=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(t+h) + f(t-h)}{1}=2f(t).
\end{gather*}

Comment: thanks  a lot @ m.strochyk   but  im not getting f(t+h) + f(t-h) = 2f(t)

Comment: @legoh legoh That is not what it states, it states $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}(f(t+h) + f(t-h))=2f(t)$, which is true by the continuity of $f$.

Comment: ok thanks @boaz moeman

Answer (score 0):

It's an immediate consequence of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Note that via FTC $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{t}^{t+h}f(s)\,ds=f(t)$$ and changing sign of $h$ in above equation we see that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{t-h}^{t}f(s)\,ds=f(t)$$ Adding these two limits we can see that the desired answer is $2f(t)$. Note that we need continuity of $f$ only at the specific point $t$ under consideration and not on whole of $\mathbb{R} $.